# How can I remove or manage my e-mail notifications?

Tags: support, status-completed, notifications, email-notification

I activated "Notify _____ daily of any new answers" when posting a question. Now I want to deactivate this option in the thread, because I'm following it via RSS feed.

I see the checkbox below the thread, I can delete the mail adress in the textbox and uncheck the checkbox, but I can't find a way to save the changes. When reloading the page, it is checked again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you weren't able to clear the checkbox - I have cleared it manually for now.